# Downsampling from 1 month to multiple months in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataset that spans 36 months. I want to downsample for periods of 3 months. I use:

```
df = df.resample('3M').sum()
```

However, when I look at the output, it does not seem to separate the period of months correctly. For example, here's 36 months of data:

```
1901-01-01    266.0
1901-02-01    145.9
1901-03-01    183.1
1901-04-01    119.3
1901-05-01    180.3
1901-06-01    168.5
1901-07-01    231.8
1901-08-01    224.5
1901-09-01    192.8
1901-10-01    122.9
1901-11-01    336.5
1901-12-01    185.9
1902-01-01    194.3
1902-02-01    149.5
1902-03-01    210.1
1902-04-01    273.3
1902-05-01    191.4
1902-06-01    287.0
1902-07-01    226.0
1902-08-01    303.6
1902-09-01    289.9
1902-10-01    421.6
1902-11-01    264.5
1902-12-01    342.3
1903-01-01    339.7
1903-02-01    440.4
1903-03-01    315.9
1903-04-01    439.3
1903-05-01    401.3
1903-06-01    437.4
1903-07-01    575.5
1903-08-01    407.6
1903-09-01    682.0
1903-10-01    475.3
1903-11-01    581.3
1903-12-01    646.9
```

If I resample this in periods of 3 months, I get the following:

```
1901-01-31     266.0
1901-04-30     448.3
1901-07-31     580.6
1901-10-31     540.2
1902-01-31     716.7
1902-04-30     632.9
1902-07-31     704.4
1902-10-31    1015.1
1903-01-31     946.5
1903-04-30    1195.6
1903-07-31    1414.2
1903-10-31    1564.9
1904-01-31    1228.2
```

If we look at the first element, instead of summing the first 3 months, it outputs only the first month. After that, it takes the following three months and starts summing them and repeats this until it reaches the end of the dataset. The final point in the output only sums the last two points in the dataset. Not to mention the dates are all messed up. I'm expecting:

```
1901-03-31
1901-06-30
1901-09-31
```

and not

```
1901-01-31
1901-04-30
1901-07-31
1901-10-31
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need parameter `closed='left'` it looks for the latest possible start, because default parameter `closed='rigth'` looks for the earliest possible start.

Docs of [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

> **closed** : {‘right’, ‘left’}
>
> Which side of bin interval is closed. The default is ‘left’ for all frequency offsets except for ‘M’, ‘A’, ‘Q’, ‘BM’, ‘BA’, ‘BQ’, and ‘W’ which all have a default of ‘right’.

```
df = df.resample('3M',closed='left').sum()
print (df)
               col
1901-03-31   595.0
1901-06-30   468.1
1901-09-30   649.1
1901-12-31   645.3
1902-03-31   553.9
1902-06-30   751.7
1902-09-30   819.5
1902-12-31  1028.4
1903-03-31  1096.0
1903-06-30  1278.0
1903-09-30  1665.1
1903-12-31  1703.5
```

---

```
df = df.resample('3M').sum()
#df = df.resample('3M',closed='right').sum()
print (df)
               col
1901-01-31   266.0
1901-04-30   448.3
1901-07-31   580.6
1901-10-31   540.2
1902-01-31   716.7
1902-04-30   632.9
1902-07-31   704.4
1902-10-31  1015.1
1903-01-31   946.5
1903-04-30  1195.6
1903-07-31  1414.2
1903-10-31  1564.9
1904-01-31  1228.2
```